# How can I get elements I add with jQuery to follow the actions I've applied to a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found out that when I use jQuery to add something to a page (via `.append` ) then the class actions I've set don't seem to apply to the new elements. 
For example in my `$(document).ready` function I'll add a `$(".clickable").click(doSomething)` it works for anything that's on the page before it's called, but if I append something with a `clickable` class, then the new element won't be clickable even if it has a `clickable` class.

While I was posting I tried and realized that I could get around this by recalling the `$(".clickable").click(doSomething);` after adding the elament, but that just makes it call doSomething more times for every element I add. 
In other words if I added 5 elements when I click on a clickable class doSomething would be called 5 times in a row for 1 click.

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution so I don't have to recall any jQuery actions everytime I add an elament, perhaps there's a smarter method than append?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed there's a much better solution. Use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to attach an event handler for current and future elements having the class `clickable`.

```
$('body').on('click', '.clickable', function() {
    ..
});
```

Comment: never mind It was something else completely, I had logged this 3 times and was wondering why it repeated! :)

Answer (score 1):

use `live()` or in jquery 1.7 `on()`

```
$(".clickable").live('click',function(){

//do something

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `live` or `delegate`.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Note, if you are using the latest jquery, this has been replaced by `on`.